# Aurelia DataTables Recompile

Tags: aurelia

I've been exploring Aurelia and so far have loved what I've seen. I've come accross an issue that I'm not really sure how to solve. I used jquery datatables for large results in my current app with angular, using server side fetches. Datatables has a function you can call whenever a new row is added to the table (fnRowCallback - http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnRowCallback, or "createdRow"  - https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html#) - This is really handy as you can recompile the dom after each row (costly I know).

This enables you to reference functions that exist in the current scope (or viewModel) that the datatable exists in. For example:

In my view model:

```
export class DataTableTest{

  test(){
   alert('this is a test');
 }
```

}

In the return results from a datatable fetch:

```
{name:'blah',age:40,actions:"<a click.delegate='test();'>Test</a>"}
```

For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to recompile an element once it has been added to the dom.

Does anyone have any ideas how you could do this?

**UPDATE:** 
These are the original options I pass to datatables:

```
    var options = {
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow) {
            $compile($(nRow).contents())(scope);
        }
    };
```

I've tried the following after injecting that compiler service:

```
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow) {
               this.compiler.compile($(nRow).contents()).fragment.innerHTML;
        },
```

But I always get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined` - I do this in the "attached" function.. If I console.log(this.compiler) outside of these options, it's available. Also, we don't need to return html back to datatables, just run the compile on the contents. Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Being a newbie to all this myself, I don't have a full answer but I would suggest that the "Cannot read property..." message is due to the fact that 'this' is not referring to the class when it's within the context of the callback. Before the line where you declare your options add 'var self = this;' then use 'self.compiler...' in the callback function.

Comment: Many thanks got it to at least reference and process - it's putting <!--<view>--> tags around the cells but the function still won't execute when clicked even tho it has an "au-target-id" now - not sure why.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with the compiling - haven't got to that stage in my requirements, yet! Off to learn about dialogs next...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a compiler service to compile the element:

```
import {inject, ViewCompiler, ViewResources, Container} from 'aurelia-framework';

/**
 * Compiler service
 *
 * compiles an HTML element with aurelia
 */
@inject(ViewCompiler, ViewResources, Container)
export class Compiler {

    viewCompiler: any;
    resources: any;
    container: any;

    constructor(viewCompiler, resources, container) {
        this.viewCompiler = viewCompiler;
        this.resources = resources;
        this.container = container;
    }

    compile(templateOrFragment, ctx = null, viewSlot = null):any {
        if (typeof templateOrFragment === "string") {
            var temp = document.createElement('span');
            temp.innerHTML = templateOrFragment;
            templateOrFragment = temp;
        }

        var view = this.viewCompiler.compile(templateOrFragment, this.resources).create(this.container, ctx);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I use this in Kendo in the cell template callback function (it lets you return a string that will become the cell contents)

```
function(dataItem) {
    var cellctx = { "$item": dataItem, "$parent": ctx };
    return this.compiler.compile(templateString, cellctx).fragment.innerHTML;
}
```

(this happens in Aurelia's `bind` callback so the ctx is the executionContext)

I just wrap the current data item up in a context and alias it as `$item` so I can work with it.

Looks something like this:

```
<kendo-grid>
    <kendo-grid-col title="Main Office" field="IsMainOffice">
        <kendo-template><img if.bind="$item.IsMainOffice" src="/content/img/accept.png" /></kendo-template>
    </kendo-grid-col>
</kendo-grid>
```